# Is it important to get a job at a top university?

Tags: faculty-application, tenure-track

My postdoc was very successful, and now I got a tenure-track offer in a mid-level university. My supervisor suggests if I stay with him for one more years or two, I might be able to get a tenure track position in top universities (say, MIT, Harvard, ...).

I can establish my research and group in any reasonable environment. Is it really that important to be in top universities? Is it worth of waiting?

Comment: What's your major/field? Maybe this information can help those who can answer your question.

Comment: I don't know, how important is for you going to a top university? How much would it cost you to wait?

Comment: Bear in mind that your supervisor may not be entirely impartial - he may be keen to persuade you to stay and continue your research with him for longer. That's not to say ignore his advice completely, just to take it with a pinch of salt.

Comment: Only you can answer what is important to your life! I know amazing researchers in """lower""" universities because of personal reasons. (note the 's in lower, that is not a correct term!). Sometimes to be near family, city preferences, etc etc... Plenty of factors, only you can judge yours, and live with the decision....

Comment: So a prof that guarantees the future. Hmmmm